# Play framework 1.2.4 to do list application using java and eclipse

Tags: playframework

How can I make a "todo list" on Play 1.2.4 version?

Comment: By reading the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/home) and then using that knowledge to create a ToDo list app ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very very easily.

1. You need a simple Model class that contains your Todo details.
2. A simple index page which displays the list of Todo objects and has a form to create a new Todo item.
3. A simple controller that has two actions. First action is to render the index page, therefore needs to call `Todo.findAll()` or similar to pass in all Todo items to the index page. Second action is to pass in a Todo object. This should be as simple as calling `save()` on the Todo object, and redirecting back to the index page.

I could probably write some code for you, but it really is as simple as described above.

Also, the old Play website had a 10 minute video to show the power of Play, and in that video Guillaume created a Todo list application. You can find the video below...

http://player.vimeo.com/video/7087610

Answer (score 0):

You can start following the **yabe** example [Play! Yabe](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide1)